# zig `@ptrToInt()` "error: unable to evaluate constant expression"

Tags: zig

I'm attempting to call iotcl to get a terminal size like so:

```
const std = @import("std");

fn ioctl_TIOCGWINSZ(fd: std.os.fd_t, ws: *std.os.linux.winsize) !void {
    while (true) {
        switch (std.os.errno(std.os.linux.ioctl(fd, std.os.linux.T.IOCGWINSZ, @ptrToInt(ws)))) {
            .SUCCESS => return,
            .INTR => continue,
            .INVAL => unreachable, // invalid request or argument
            .BADF => unreachable,  // fd is not a file descriptor
            .FAULT => unreachable, // invalid argument
            .NOTTY => return std.os.TermiosGetError.NotATerminal, //  fd is not a tty
            else => |err| return std.os.unexpectedErrno(err),
        }
    }
}

pub fn getTerminalSize(handle: std.os.fd_t) !type {

    var size : std.os.linux.winsize = undefined;
    try ioctl_TIOCGWINSZ(handle, &size);

    return .{ size.ws_col, size.ws_row };
}
```

with the call to `getTerminalSize` being:

```
    var size = try tz.getTerminalSize(std.os.STDOUT_FILENO);
```

However, this produces a compiler error like so:

```
./libs/terz/terminal.zig:40:79: error: unable to evaluate constant expression
        switch (std.os.errno(std.os.linux.ioctl(fd, std.os.linux.T.IOCGWINSZ, @ptrToInt(ws)))) {
                                                                              ^
./libs/terz/terminal.zig:55:25: note: called from here
    try ioctl_TIOCGWINSZ(handle, &size);
                        ^
./src/main.zig:15:42: note: called from here
        var size = try tz.getTerminalSize(std.os.STDOUT_FILENO);
                                         ^
./src/main.zig:5:29: note: called from here
pub fn main() anyerror!void {
                            ^
./libs/terz/terminal.zig:40:48: note: referenced here
        switch (std.os.errno(std.os.linux.ioctl(fd, std.os.linux.T.IOCGWINSZ, @ptrToInt(ws)))) {
                                               ^
./libs/terz/terminal.zig:55:25: note: referenced here
    try ioctl_TIOCGWINSZ(handle, &size);
                        ^
./src/main.zig:15:42: note: referenced here
        var size = try tz.getTerminalSize(std.os.STDOUT_FILENO);
                                         ^
```

In `std/os/linux.zig`, `ioctl` is defined as:

```
pub fn ioctl(fd: fd_t, request: u32, arg: usize) usize {
    return syscall3(.ioctl, @bitCast(usize, @as(isize, fd)), request, arg);
}
```

And in `std.os.zig` there's a function (that presumably works) similar to what I'm trying to do:

```
pub fn ioctl_SIOCGIFINDEX(fd: fd_t, ifr: *ifreq) IoCtl_SIOCGIFINDEX_Error!void {
    while (true) {
        switch (errno(system.ioctl(fd, SIOCGIFINDEX, @ptrToInt(ifr)))) {
            .SUCCESS => return,
            .INVAL => unreachable, // Bad parameters.
            .NOTTY => unreachable,
            .NXIO => unreachable,
            .BADF => unreachable, // Always a race condition.
            .FAULT => unreachable, // Bad pointer parameter.
            .INTR => continue,
            .IO => return error.FileSystem,
            .NODEV => return error.InterfaceNotFound,
            else => |err| return unexpectedErrno(err),
        }
    }
}
```

Is this a compiler bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like there's a couple of things wrong with my `getTerminalSize()`, and the error message is pointing at the wrong culprit here.

`getTerminalSize()` shouldn't be returning `type`. To return an anonymous struct, the syntax would be:

```
pub fn getTerminalSize(handle: std.os.fd_t) !struct{ width: u16, height: u16 } {

    var size : std.os.linux.winsize = undefined;
    try ioctl_TIOCGWINSZ(handle, &size);

    return .{ .width = size.ws_col, .height = size.ws_row };
}
```

However, [zig doesn't currently support returning anonymous structs unioned with an error type](https://github.com/ziglang/zig/issues/3662).

So for the moment, the solution is to name the struct:

```
pub const TerminalSize = struct {
    width: u16,
    height: u16,
};

pub fn getTerminalSize(handle: std.os.fd_t) !TerminalSize {

    var size: std.os.linux.winsize = undefined;
    try ioctl_TIOCGWINSZ(handle, &size);

    return TerminalSize{ .width = size.ws_col, .height = size.ws_row };
}
```